# insert a variable and table value as parameters to procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFruitName]
        (
@quantity int
)
    AS
    BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;

         INSERT INTO Table1(fname,fprice,quantity)
          SELECT f.name,f.price from table2 f,@quantity


    END
```

but am unable to pass @quantity

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In addition to asking a question, add the expected results. If the syntax error in the non-working code if corrected, the proc will duplicate all existing rows in the table with the new quantity, It is unclear if that's your intent.

Answer (score 1):

if @quantity is a "variable" .. I hear "input parameter" to the stored procedure ... then add it to the definition ..

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFruitName] @quantity int
AS 
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO table1(fname,fprice,quantity)
   SELECT f.name,f.price, @quantity 
      FROM Table2 as f

END
```